# Highcharts get Value from API to xAxis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I started to work on my first project and got a problem using Highcharts. My goal is it, to display the data I fetch from an stock API. I have no Problem displaying the stock price, but i don´t know how to display the stock price + closing date. I want it to look like the Google or Yahoo charting tool.

I am using the Alpha Vantage API, i the data gets provided like so:
[API documentation](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo).

My code looks like this:

```
const Stock = () => {

    const [stockChartXValues, setStockChartXValues] = useState('');
    const [stockChartYValues, setStockChartYValues] = useState('');

    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetchStock();
    }, [])

    function fetchStock() {
        const API_KEY = 'KT7CW1QXDZBDGCIH.';
        let StockSymbol = 'AAPL';
        let API_Call = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=${StockSymbol}&outputsize=compact&apikey=${API_KEY}`
        let StockChartXValuesFunction = []
        let StockChartYValuesFunction = []

        fetch(API_Call)
            .then(
                function (response) {
                    return response.json();
                }
            )
            .then(
                function (data) {

                    for (var key in data[`Time Series (Daily)`]) {
                        StockChartXValuesFunction.push(key);
                        StockChartYValuesFunction.push(parseFloat((Math.round(data[`Time Series (Daily)`][key][`2. high`] * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)));
                    }
                    setStockChartYValues(StockChartYValuesFunction);
                    setStockChartXValues(StockChartXValuesFunction);

                }
            )
    }

    const options = {

        title: {
            text: 'My stock chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            labels: {
                format: '{value:%b-%e}'
            },
        },

        series: [{
            data: stockChartYValues,
            pointStart: Date.UTC(stockChartYValues[99]),
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000

        }]
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Stock Market</h1>
            <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} constructorType={'stockChart'}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Hi @Alexander Völkening, What exactly do you want to show? Another line series with `close` values? Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-t2c92?file=/demo.jsx

Comment: This looks perfect! Thank you so much! Sorry for the late reply but I was enjoying my holidays.